# Regular Expression for allowing multiple language input

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

Quick question regarding regular expression validation on textbox entry. Basically I have a textbox that I am using for user input in the form of a website address. The user can input anything (it doesn't have to be a valid website address - i.e. www.facebook.com. They could enter "blah blah", and that's fine but it will not run.

What I am after is to validate different languages, Arabic, Greek, Chinese, etc etc, because at present I only allow English characters.

The code for the method is below. I believe I will have to switch this from a whitelist to blacklist, so instead of seeing what matches, change the expression to invalid characters, and if the user enters one of these, don't allow it.

```
public static bool IsValidAddress(string path)
    {
        bool valid = false;

        valid = (path.Length > 0);

        if (valid)
        {

            string regexPattern = @"([0-9a-zA-Z*?]{1})([-0-9a-zA-Z_\.*?]{0,254})";

            // Elimate the '"' character first up so it simplifies regular expressions.
            valid = (path.Contains("\"") == false);

            if (valid)
            {
                valid = IsValidAddress(path, regexPattern);
            }

            if (valid)
            {
                // Need an additional check to determine that the address does not begin with xn--,
                // which is not permitted by the Internationalized Domain Name standard.
                valid = (path.IndexOf("xn--") != 0);
            }
        }

        return valid;
    }
```

As you can see, I have the 0-9a-zA-Z included, but by default this will eliminate other languages, whereas I wish to include the languages.

Any help is greatly appreciated. If I've confused anyone, sorry! I can give more information if it is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to validate a URL/URI? You can use existing function in C#.

Comment: as far as I know, the `a-zA-Z` pattern is used for `English alphabets` only, you should include each character yourself for any other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're trying to validate Uri's with Regex. .Net's Uri class is surely a much better match to your task, no?

```
Uri uri;
if(!Uri.TryParse(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
    //it's a bad URI
}
```

Comment: Hi spender, thanks for that I will look into using it. As you can probably tell I'm a bit of a noob in the programming world! Never heard of the URI class so will check that out thanks! Still finding my way around the wonderful world of C#!